# How do I add a custom Build Action to the list in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

If you bring up the properties for a project item in Visual Studio, in the "Advanced" category, there's a "Build Action" property. In my installation of Visual Studio, it contains "None", "Compile", "Content", etc..

If I attempt to type an unrecognised value in the box, I get the warning "Property value is not valid".

**Is it possible to add my own values to this list? If so, how?**

I'm not asking about how to add custom build types to the MSBuild project file -- I already know how to do that. It's just that I'm *too lazy* to "Unload Project" / "Edit Project" / change `<None Include="Foo.bar"/>` to `<Whatever Include="Foo.bar"/>` / "Reload Project" / "Yes, I'm sure I want to reload the project even though it's already open in the editor".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/10/06/477064.aspx), create the following ItemsGroup in your csproj file (or in an imported .targets file):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AvailableItemName Include="Whatever" />   
</ItemGroup>
```

You should see another option in the list.

Comment: Worked perfectly to temporarily re-introduce `TypeScriptCompile` items and make the files appear in Visual Studio after migrating to SDK-style csproj using an older version of `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild`.

Comment: Also, you might want to revisit and update the link in your answer as it is currently broken.